# Boostrap: Navigation points should stack in mobile view and padding inside navigation points should not overlap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap to build a responsive design. Now I wanted to create a simple responsive footer navigation. Actually it turns out that it is not that simple. I am currently facing one issue and would like to realize one improvement.

**Issue**

As soon as the navigation points begin to stack the padding of the navigation points overlap, but they should not overlap. I already did some research in the web and tried different approaches, but none did work so far for me.

**Improvement**

The navigation points should stack in mobile view, but should be inline with bigger viewport sizes. My feeling is that realizing this feature request will also solve the issue described above. But I am not sure how to setup bootstrap properly.

Maybe a more experienced developer can suggest how to archive that targets.

I also created a jsfiddle example available at

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- Bootstrap uses HTML5 elements and CSS3 properties -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Enable IE compatibility mode. -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- Scales the viewport width and height to the max. browser window -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Document</title>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <ul id="footer--navigation">
            <li><a href="#">Test-Category</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test-Category</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test-Category</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test-Category</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test-Category</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/herbert_hinterberger/y6kcgkbe/1/

Many thanks in advance. 
Herbert

Comment: You have missed off your JSFiddle link

Comment: @JamesKing: Just added it. Seems I need to post from now on also some relevant code on stackoverflow if I want to use an example on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, then you just need to add display: inline-block to your footer links:

```
#footer--navigation li > a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Without that, the top and bottom padding on the links will not be applied